# oracle query select json field

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Database: Oracle 19c

My table

```
tck_id ; sw_j

1001 ; [{id:1,desc:title1},{id:2,desc:title2}]
```

sw_j:  VARCHAR2(4000)  with is_json check constraint

Result i want

```
tck_id ; id ; desc

1001 ; 1 ; title1
1001 ; 2 ; title2
```

the value in sw_j is always an array of objects. In docs Oracle the example "LineItems"
[(link to docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-0172660F-CE29-4765-BF2C-C405BDE8369A)
is an array of objects but of a specific key, in my case i don't have a key.

Comment: so? what is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give a table name, but the syntax for the expression to unnest the elements will be something like this.

```
select * 
from json_table(
        '[{id:1,desc:"title1"},{id:2,desc:"title2"}]','$[*]'
            columns 
                (id number PATH '$.id' error on error,
                 descr varchar2(4000) PATH '$.desc' error on error)) j;
```